# TFS Error TF53001: The database operation was canceled by an administrator

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I use visual studio team foundation server 2013 on windows server 2008 R2 and SQL SERVER 2014, When I want to "get latest" or "check in" files from Microsoft visual studio occurred this error:
TF53001: The database operation was canceled by an administrator.
So, One of the projects on the server is in trouble and the others do not have problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this trouble before, you should update your sql server to latest service pack version.
try this one https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/8/2F8F7165-BB21-4D1E-B5D8-3BD3CE73C77D/SQLServer2014SP1-KB3058865-x64-ENU.exe

Answer (score 1):

We had just the same issue.

> The service account had been disabled.

It seems some data was cached somewhere on client such that some collections seemed operational on the clients which are used to working with that collection. but actually for many operations it was not working (for example creating a new repository
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My TFS 2013.4 server suddenly started doing this.

I eventually changed the Compatibility Level of the TFS databases to Server 2014 (120) and restarted TFS, and it worked!

Strange thing, the other Team Project Collections still worked, it was just the one we were busy on that had this issue....